# Rendering rails named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, renderaction, named-routing

How do I render a rails named route properly from controller?

routes.rb:

```
get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"

root :to => "home#index"

resources :users
resources :sessions
resources :likes
```

user_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  if @user.save
    login(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Problem is: the signup page is on `/signup` and when the data in `@user` is not filled out properly and `render :new` is called, instead of going to the url `/signup` it goes to `/users`.  I would use `redirect_to` but id prefer not to because I want the errors saved off on the page to tell the users which data was not provided.

Update after added `match "signup" => "users#create", :via => "post"`

```
root             /                            {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
users     GET    /users(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user      GET    /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
signup    GET    /signup(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /signup(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's normal because it's rendering the :new method of users. What is the problem with that ?

Comment: Well Ideally I would like the url to stay on /signup instead of going to /users

Comment: ok so look at Joel Friedlaender answer then. But if you look at REST, you GET /users/new, when you create it POST /users but if there is any errors it render :new with the URL /users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this route also:

```
match "signup" => "users#create", :via => "post"
```

Comment: What does your "new" method look like in your controller, perhaps update your question with it?

Comment: Looking at it further, it looks like your resources :users could be overriding the earlier route. I would guess if you removed that it will work. If that's the case, you could change it to "resources :users, :except => :new"

Comment: got it added form_for @user, :url => signup_path.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In **routes.rb** You can add

```
get "signup", to: "users#new"
post "signup", to: "users#create"
put "signup", to: "users#update"
```

And in Registration **form**  - Check *signup_path*

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: signup_path, html: {method: 'post'})
```

For *Other Readers* who has used **devise_for :users**, can defined routes as:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "signup", to: "devise/registrations#new"
  post "signup", to: "devise/registrations#create"
  put "signup", to: "devise/registrations#update"
end
```

And Registration **form** as above.

By adding this routes, you can use your named routes like (register, signup) even after user fills register form with some error.